# ng-show not showing with variable check

Tags: angularjs

This is my controller:

```
capApp.controller('cookieCtrl', ['$scope','$cookies', function($scope, $cookies) {
  var cookieSet = $cookies.user_id;
  alert('coolkie is ' + cookieSet); // this is fine and shows the value
}]);
```

And the nav I want to show:

```
<div id="siteNav2" ng-controller="cookieCtrl">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" ng-show="cookieSet">
    ... all nav here ...
  </nav>
</div>
```

But it shows, then disappears...

I also tried, but same result:

```
ng-show="cookieSet != null"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it to a `$scope` var:

```
$scope.cookieSet = $cookies.user_id;
```

Regular `var` variables are not accessible in the view.

Comment: Ah, that I did not know, thanks for the explanation too!